# Are questions about transferring an image onto a specific surface okay?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I'm not quite sure whether this site is okay for asking questions about drawing on real life objects.

For example, I want to make a caption on a plastic bucket and I want the caption to look good - of right size, with right letters, laid out properly, etc. Don't forget that a bucket is a truncated cone, so I'd need to first print (or draw) the caption elsewhere, make sure it's of right size and then transfer the contours onto the bucket surface and redraw it there and have the contours properly deformed to compensate for the cone shape of the bucket.

Would a question about specific techniques to perform this sequence be on-topic here?

Answer (score 3):

I dont have a problem with questions like this.  My understanding of the intention for GD is to help the creative process with a question that can have an EXACT answer which could help someone in the future.  If your question is clear, well written, within design, and unique I am sure you shouldn't have a problem.

However, if your question is broad, opinion based, on Mars then your question would probably be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Matt, I think it would be fine here. Just be sure to include details about as much as possible: the size and shape of the bucket, what sort of imprint (how many colors? how will it be printed?), what materials you have available.

The only precedent I can think of for a question like this is this one: [**Designing for Coffee Mugs**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/16315/8708). It's on a different track, but shares some similarities with what you'd like to ask.